# How to interact with (MySQL) Databases in JSF

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, phpmyadmin

I come from PHP and am trying to build a Web Application with JSF. I really like the simplicity of some tasks with JSF, (for instance the use of Ajax) but when it comes to database integration I am very confused and don't know where and how to start, no matter how much I am reading about it.

In the past I simply created and administrated my MySQL databases in PhpMyAdmin and did the connection via PHP, in JSF it seems to be way more difficult.

I am using Apache Tomcat as Servlet Container, can I even run PhpMyAdmin on Tomcat? Furthermore I read about some different approaches to accessing the databases in the Web Application, like JPA and JDBC using Hibernate as a connection tool.

So what I am basically asking for in this question is for beginner tips and tutorials regarding database connection in Java Server Faces. Also I want to know if there is a way I could still use PhpMyAdmin to manage and create my databases.

I am sorry for this question beeing so generic, but after hours of researching this topic is still so unclear to me that I would love to get some information from experienced people.

Comment: Yes, you can still use PhpMyAdmin. Just install it separately. It's not forbidden to have 2 web servers running at the same machine (only do it at different ports, but that's nothing more than obvious). Even more, you can use the one (usually HTTPD) as proxy of the other (usually Tomcat). This has additional benefits like e.g. the possibility to have a maintenance page. For the remainder, better look for a discussion forum. This can't have a single answer which is acceptable by everyone now and in the future (which is what a Q&A site like Stack Exchange is all about).

Comment: DB layer has more to do with your application architecture rather than with JSF itself, which has to be bounded to the view layer. I mean, for JSF should not matter to work with MySql or Postgre. You are looking probably for a prototype design of the architecture and a dependency injecting tool (see Spring or CDI) which will help you building your layers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only for the beginning and understanding how to establish a connection to db in JSF, i'll give you an example how to do it manually without using any other Frameworks, later you could use Hibernate or what ever you want.

1-) be sure that your mysql server is running

2-) create a new dynamic web Project(if not already exists)

3-) download the mysql Connector jar file and put it under web-inf/lib

4-) in your web.xml define the DB Vars. something like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>JDBC-DRIVER</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>DB-SERVER</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name...</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>DB-USER</param-name>
    <param-value>root or your db username</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>DB-PASSWORD</param-name>
    <param-value>...db user password ...</param-value>
</context-param>
```

5-) create a simple Database Connection Manager example:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;


public class DBM implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9204275723046653468L;
    private String db_server   = "";
    private String db_user     = "";
    private String db_password = "";
    private String db_driver   = "";

    public Connection connection = null;

    public DBM() throws Exception {
        init();
    }

    private void init()throws Exception{
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        db_server   = fc.getExternalContext().getInitParameter("DB-SERVER");
        db_user     = fc.getExternalContext().getInitParameter("DB-USER");
        db_password = fc.getExternalContext().getInitParameter("DB-PASSWORD");
        db_driver   = fc.getExternalContext().getInitParameter("JDBC-DRIVER");
        Class.forName(db_driver);
    }   

    public Connection initConnection() throws Exception{
        if( this.connection == null ){
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(db_server, db_user, db_password);
            this.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        }else if( this.connection.isClosed() ){
            this.connection = null;
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(db_server, db_user, db_password);
            this.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        }
        return this.connection;
    }

    public void closeConnection(){
        try {
            if( this.connection != null ){
                this.connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void commitConnection(){
        try {
            if( this.connection != null && !this.connection.isClosed() ){
                this.connection.commit();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void rollbackConnection(){
        try {
            if( this.connection != null && !this.connection.isClosed() ){
                this.connection.rollback();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

6-) now lets create a test Class named User where we use the db Connection:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class User implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7667553477247791348L;
    private int id;
    private String name;    
    private String category;
    private static String db_table = "db table name of this class";

    public User(){

    }
    public User(int id, String name, String cat) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.category = cat;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public static List<User> getListByCategory(DBM dbm, String cid, boolean close) throws Exception{
        List<User> list            = new ArrayList<User>();
        PreparedStatement preState = null;
        ResultSet resultSet        = null;
        try {
            if( dbm == null ){
                dbm = new DBM();
            }
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+db_table+" WHERE _CATEGORY_ID=?";
            preState   = dbm.initConnection().prepareStatement(sql); 
            preState.setString(1, cid);
            resultSet  = preState.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                list.add( new User(resultSet.getInt(1),resultSet.getString(2),resultSet.getString(3)) );                
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if( preState != null )
                preState.close();
            if( close && dbm.connection != null )
                dbm.connection.close();         
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```